# basic integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Consider $0 < r <R $. I have a function $u \in C_{0}^{\infty}(B(x_0,R))$ such that $u=1$ on $\overline{B(x_0,r)}$  . Consider $y \in \partial B(0,1)$ (fixed) . My book says :

$$ 1 \leq  \int_{r}^{R} |\frac{d}{ds}u(sy)| \ ds$$

I tried to begin with $\frac{d}{ds}u(sy) = \nabla u(sy) . y$ and this is zero if $s \leq r$. but I dont know what happen if $s > r$ ...

Someone can give me a hand to prove the inequality ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I think that $x_0=0$?

Comment: no...  $x_o$ is arbitrary .

Comment: So, there is a incosistency in your problem: you have taked $y\in \partial B(0,1)$.

Comment: Maybe you wanna mean $u(x_0+sy)$ in the integral?

Comment: you're right @Tomás .I dont note this fact. my book is wrong rsrs. thanks. i think if I define $f(s) = u(sy)$ (let's consider x_0 = 0) and if I use the fundamental theorem of calculus  $f(R) - F(r) = \displaystyle\int_{r}^{R} \frac{d}{ds} u(sy) \ ds$ I solve the problem ( note that $f(r) = 1$ and $f(R) = 0$ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the way you have stated the problem, it does not make sense, because $sy$ does not need to belong to $B(x_0,R)$. Probably what you do wanna prove is $$\tag{1}1\leq \int_r^R \left|\frac{d}{ds}u(x_0+sy)\right|$$

To prove $(1)$, define $v(s)=u(x_0+sy)$ and note that $$\tag{2}v(R)-v(r)=\int_r^R \frac{d}{ds}v(s)ds $$

From $(2)$ we conclude that $$|v(R)-v(r)|\leq\int_r^R\left|\frac{d}{ds}v(s)\right|ds$$

But $|v(R)-v(r)|=1$ which implies that $$1\leq \int_r^R\left|\frac{d}{ds}u(x_0+sy)\right|ds$$

Comment: Obrigado @Tomás !

Comment: De nada @LeandroTavares